# How to remove symbols from both sides of a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How would I go about removing characters from the left side of a Python string? Example:

```
string='@!#word '
```

I know I can use `strip('@!# ')` to get

```
string='word'
```

but I need a general code to remove all the characters that are not alphabet

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex.

```
import re
string='@!#word '
print(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', string))
```

**Output:**

```
word
```

---

Use this if you need to remove special chars on the sides.

**Ex:**

```
import string
s='@!#word '
print(s.rstrip(string.punctuation).lstrip(string.punctuation))
```

**Output:**

```
word
```

Comment: What if its integer ?

Answer (score 0):

*"code to remove all the characters that are not alphabet"*   If you are looking for this you can try using join :

```
string='@!#word '
new_str = ''.join(i for i in string if i.isalpha())
print(new_str)
```

O/p will be like :

```
'word'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function to do that with the help of string functions.

```
string='@!#word '
string = filter(str.isalnum, string)
print string
```

Comment: But I could see the type is already the string .
>>> string='@!#word '
>>> string = filter(str.isalnum, string)
>>> type(string)
<type 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression that matches the beginning of the string and all non-alpha characters after it:

```
import re
re.sub(r'^[A-Za-z]*', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only cleans at start and stop, non-regex, special chars inside will be preserved:

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters

text ='@!#word @! word  '

def cleanMe(text):
    t = list(text)
    while t and t[0] not in letters:
        t[:] = t[1:] # shorten list as long as non-letters are in front
    while t and t[-1] not in letters:
        t[:] = t[:-1] # shorten list as long as non-letters are in back

    return ''.join(t)

w = cleanMe(text)

print (w)
```

Output:

```
word @! word
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes all non-alphabets and non-integers from both ends of the string while preserving special characters appearing within the string:

```
import re, string

name = "@!#word"
al_nums = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', string.printable)
extra_chars = ''.join([i for i in name if i not in al_nums])

print(name.strip(extra_chars))
# word
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```
a=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
name = "@!#word"
i=0
b=[]
for i in range(0,len(name)):
    if(name[i] in a):
        b.append(name[i])
b=''.join(b)
print(b)
```

- A **list** is created with lower case & upper case alphabets.
  Individual elements of the string is tested against the list using
  **is**. If True, the element is appended to an empty list.
- Finally, joining the list gives the characters that are only alphabets.

  I've only just begun learning Python. Please let me know if this method isn't pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to strip characters from both sides (i.e. do not remove symbols in the middle):

```
string = '@!#word '
s, e = 0, len(string)
while s < e and not string[s].isalpha():
    s += 1
while s < e and not string[e - 1].isalpha():
    e -= 1
print(string[s:e])
```